# How to create vertical lines between items in menu with :after selector

Tags: css

I have a menu with borders half way up besides each element (supposed to be between every element except first one). I try to achieve this with the after-selector, e.g. a:not(:first-child):before but it doesn't work. Look at the example below, the first vertical line should be removed. The code for the vertical lines has been marked below in the code.

```css
.meny 
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}

.meny li 
{
    float: left;
}

.meny li a 
{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 17px 20px 15px 20px;
    position: relative; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Below is the code for the vertical lines */

.meny li a:after 
{
    content:""; 
    background: white; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    height: 60%; 
    width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="meny">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
</div>
```

Any tips?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The parent of a `<li>` element cannot be a `<div>`. Also note that you are attempting to create a pseudo-element and not a "selector". That now requires two colons to be proper because the specification changed years ago. One colon will still work but that is for pseudo-classes now. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this like below code:

```
.meny li:first-child a:after{
   display: none;
}
```

```css
.meny 
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}

.meny li 
{
    float: left;
}

.meny li a 
{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 17px 20px 15px 20px;
    position: relative; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Below is the code for the vertical lines */

.meny li a:after 
{
    content:""; 
    background: white; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 1.5px;
}
.meny li:first-child a:after 
{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="meny">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
</div>
```

Comment: I see what you did, could you explain why I have to use "li:first-child a:after" and not "li a:after(first-child)" for example? Just want to understand it a little bit better.

Comment: I have used "li:first-child a:after" because first, you need to find the first LI of ul then you can apply any CSS on that child element and "A" tag is first child of every LI if you will apply property on "LI" "A" first child then that property will aplly on every "a" tag.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there.

Replace

```
.meny li a:after {
```

with

`.meny > li:not(:first-child) a:after {`

This will avoid the first vertical line

```
.meny > li:not(:first-child) a:after {
    content:""; 
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0px; 
    height: 60%; 
    width: 1.5px;
    top: 20%; /*center lines vertically*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned before

> I try a:not(:first-child):before but it doesn't work

You have tried select the first link of your menu, but `.meny` has 4 children `li` and every `li` has 1 child `a`. So, if you want to achieve the first one you have to call `li` and get his child `a`.

```
.meny li:not(:first-child) a::before 
{
    content:""; 
    background: white; 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    transform: translateY(-30%); // Centered element
    height: 60%; 
    width: 1.5px;
}
```